# Using Phonegap PushPlugin does not open App when in background and Push Notification arrives

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, phonegap-plugins

I'm using the Phonegap plugin "PushPlugin" (https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin) together with Phonegap 2.9.0 for iOS and Android. For iOS everything works as expected: A notification arrives, I click on the notification and the app is started.

On Android, we distinguish between two cases: The app is in foreground (active) or in background (closed or just not actively used). When I receive a notification while in foreground, the plugin works. When I receive a notification while in background, the plugin creates a notification in the notification bar, but tapping on the notification does not open my app.

The relevant code that should open my app is:

```
//  Gets called when the notification arrives
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onMessage - context: " + context);

    // Extract the payload from the message
    final Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null)
    {
        final boolean   foreground = this.isInForeground();

        extras.putBoolean("foreground", foreground);

        if (foreground)
            PushPlugin.sendExtras(extras);
        else
            createNotification(context, extras);
    }
}

    // This creates the notification in the notification bar, but a click on the notification does not open my app
public void createNotification(Context context, Bundle extras)
{
    final NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    final String appName = getAppName(this);

    final Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, PushHandlerActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("pushBundle", extras);

    final PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    final NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
    .setSmallIcon(context.getApplicationInfo().icon)
    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
    .setContentTitle(appName)
    .setTicker(appName)
    .setContentIntent(contentIntent);

    final String message = extras.getString("message");
    if (message != null) {
        mBuilder.setContentText(message);
    } else {
        mBuilder.setContentText("<missing message content>");
    }

    final String msgcnt = extras.getString("msgcnt");
    if (msgcnt != null) {
        mBuilder.setNumber(Integer.parseInt(msgcnt));
    }

    mNotificationManager.notify(appName, NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    tryPlayRingtone();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought it was a problem similar to https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/issues/35#issuecomment-24722796, but it was simply an issue with the Android Manifest: The PushPlugin activity was entered with a wrong package.