# Apigee push notifications on Android not delivered when app in background (Phonegap)

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, apigee, phonegap-pushplugin

I am trying to use apigee push notifications with Android phonegap app build 3.3.0, PushPlugin.
My push notifications sent when the app is in foreground are displayed correctly, but when the app is in background they are not shown.

It looks like the issue is that apigee sends a push with payload that contains "data" property (e.payload.data), instead of "message" property, and since there is no "message" property and that's why android does not display it.

Can you please advise if it is possible to change the payload format of apigee push messages or make the phonegap app to handle "data" in the payload correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how flexible the phone gap plugin is regarding background processing, but yes, you may provide any payload you'd like when you create the message to push to your devices.

If you look Apigee's [Creating and managing notifications](http://apigee.com/docs/app-services/content/creating-and-managing-notifications) document, you'll see in each example, there is a  that can specified. If it is a JSON object (instead of a string), it will be delivered "as is" to the client. In other words, you could specify during notification creation that the  for your notifier is something like:

{ "message" : "my message" }.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is interesting, I just tried to send a json from the apigee portal and it still translates it as payload: {"data":"{ \"message\" : \"my message\" }"}

Comment: I tried using API to send a push with custom json but it still sends it as {"data":"{ \"message\" : \"my message\" }"}. Can you please advise?

Comment: I was using javascript API as simple as:             
var client = new Apigee.Client({ .... });
var json = "{ \"message\" : \"my message\" }";
var androidOptions = {
    notifier: "androidDev",
    path: devicePath,
    message: json
};
client.sendPushToDevice(androidOptions, callback);

Comment: Try to leave your json message as a javascript object instead of converting it to a string.

Comment: Otherwise, did you see this related question? Perhaps you're having a similar manifest naming issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19012354/using-phonegap-pushplugin-does-not-open-app-when-in-background-and-push-notifica?rq=1

Comment: Genius! Using javascript object works and android receives push notifications when app is in background! Thanks a lot!